# No known instance method for selector error in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a problem accessing a object in my array. I store "Place" objects in my NSMutableArray. I want to access this array for my TableView. I get the "No known instance method for selector" error in line one. See lines below.

```
cell.imageView = [[self.currentPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]picture];
cell.subtitleLB.text = [[self.currentPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description];
cell.objectNameLB.text = [[self.currentPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
```

This is my Place object:

```
@interface Place : NSObject{

CLLocation *objectLocation;
UIImageView *picture;
NSString *name;
NSString *description;
}
```

The access of the properties "description" and "name" is no problem. I just dont know why this error occurs.

Thx. Dominik

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; what worked for me was passing the UIImage instead of the UIImageView. So your code should look like this:

```
@interface Place : NSObject{

CLLocation *objectLocation;
UIImage *picture;
NSString *name;
NSString *description;
}
```

and this

```
cell.imageView.image = [[self.currentPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]picture];
cell.subtitleLB.text = [[self.currentPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description];
cell.objectNameLB.text = [[self.currentPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
```

If that doesn't work I'll post some more code for you to look at.

Comment: I tried a couple things.. so I found the issue. I forgot to import the "Place.h" file in my TableView Class. ;( So stupid. I just don't know know why the "description" and "name" attribute are worked.

Comment: @user1185486: See my answer. Even with the import it won't work, since you didn't actually declare methods. `-description` works because it's on `NSObject. `-name` will compile, because it exists on other objects and you're calling it on an `id`-typed value, but it will fail at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually declared any methods. What you have declared are instance variables. You should probably be using `@property`s instead.

```
@interface Place : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *objectLocation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *picture;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy, getter=objectDescription) NSString *description;
@end
```

This will actually create the methods that you want. Note that I changed the method for the `description` property to read `-objectDescription`. This is because `NSObject` already declares the `-description` method and you shouldn't be overriding it with an unrelated property.

If you're on recent Clang, then this is all you need, and instance variables will get synthesized automatically (using an underbar prefix, e.g. `_picture`). If you're on an older version (e.g. if this causes errors), you need to add `@synthesize` lines, as in

```
@implementation Place
@synthesize objectLocation=_objectLocation;
@synthesize picture=_picture;
@synthesize name=_name;
@synthesize description=_description;
@end
```